# Why (sometimes) Membership.ValidateUser first invoke PasswordFormat and how?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-membership

I've running `MVC` project on a machine. I've set a custom membership in the web config such as:

```
<membership defaultProvider="CustomMembership">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="CustomMembership" type="GotPayments.CustomAuthentication.CustomMembership"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

I've implemented some functions that I need; for the others, I just thrown a `NotImplementedException`, since I don't use it. So when I call my implemented `ValidateUser` user, all works ok:

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string email, string password)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
    {
        return false;
    }

    using (MyProject ctx = new MyProject())
    {
        var user = (from us in ctx.Users
                    where string.Compare(email, us.Email, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0
                    && string.Compare(password, us.Password, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0
                    && us.IsActive == true
                    select us).FirstOrDefault();

        return (user != null) ? true : false;
    }
}
```

But, once I copy the project on another machine, and I run it, the same fuction (before being executed; so F11 while debugging don't enter to `ValidateUser`) call this:

```
public override MembershipPasswordFormat PasswordFormat
{
    get
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

which throw an exception.

Why do it call it only "sometimes"? And how the framework call it? 
I never call that function myself.

StackTrace:

```
in System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)  
in System.Environment.get_StackTrace() 
in MyProject.CustomAuthentication.CustomMembership.get_PasswordFormat() in CustomMembership.cs:riga 117
in System.Web.Security.Membership.CheckedPasswordFormat(MembershipProviderCollection providers)
in System.Web.Security.Membership.Initialize()
in System.Web.Security.Membership.get_Provider()
in System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(String username, String password)
in MyProject.Controllers.AccountController.Login(LoginViewModel loginView) in AccountController.cs:riga 27
```

Login.cs

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel loginView)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(loginView.Email, loginView.Password))
        {
            // ...
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Oh my... is that a case-insensitive clear-text password verification? That's even worse than the common clear-text password verification nightmare commonly seen

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace at the moment it enters `PasswordFormat.get`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Do you mean `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace t = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();`? Which method?

Comment: It could be that or the output from the stack trace window from Visual Studio (if debugging, of course). I meant when it gets to the `PasswordFormat` property

Comment: Posted. Is it correct? is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, thanks. It seems that the problem might be in another provider, unrelated to yours. Can you post the `Login` action code?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: did!

Comment: So? No one can help me?

Comment: The problem does not seem to be your code, but rather another provider executing or some configuration calling a virtual member. I do not want to post an answer because I don't know enough to be certain about what exactly is triggering that check

Comment: But how can that PasswordFormat be called between my `if (Membership.ValidateUser(loginView.Email, loginView.Password))` and the first line of code of `ValidateUser`? Thats make me wonder :O

Comment: That's easily understood from the stack trace: `ValidateUser` calls `Provider.get` (a property) which instead calls `Initialize`

Comment: Not sure what you mean: can my own function call (before being executed) another function without that I write it? How? Attribute?

Comment: No, you are using `System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(String username, String password)`, a built-in method. You don't have nor can change that source code . That method is what is causing the problem

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: nope, looks at my code. I've override it... `public override bool ValidateUser(string email, string password)` that's why I don't get who call that `PasswordFormat ` between my call and the body of that function...